# Clicking on a button in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to train selenium and scratch some information on website: https://www.stepstone.at/?gclid=CjwKCAiApNSABhAlEiwANuR9YAJKRjy_7hDuKPpJRL-zfaqDqc2zlAo9EgGmRHgs1Bvx5WRu_3ZPkBoC9_cQAvD_BwE&&ef_id=CjwKCAiApNSABhAlEiwANuR9YAJKRjy_7hDuKPpJRL-zfaqDqc2zlAo9EgGmRHgs1Bvx5WRu_3ZPkBoC9_cQAvD_BwE:G:s&cid=SEAdvert_Google_SEARCH_AT_Gen-E_c_Jobs_jobs_FPd_EtaId4-L1&loc_interest=&loc_physical=1000852&s_kwcid=AL!524!3!494891721515!e!!g!!jobs

This is my code:

```
search_job = input("Write your job that you are searching for: ")
search_city = input("Write your city where you want to find your job: ")
search_working_times = input("Write your working times: ")
PATH = "C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.stepstone.at/?gclid=CjwKCAiApNSABhAlEiwANuR9YAJKRjy_7hDuKPpJRL-zfaqDqc2zlAo9EgGmRHgs1Bvx5WRu_3ZPkBoC9_cQAvD_BwE&&ef_id=CjwKCAiApNSABhAlEiwANuR9YAJKRjy_7hDuKPpJRL-zfaqDqc2zlAo9EgGmRHgs1Bvx5WRu_3ZPkBoC9_cQAvD_BwE:G:s&cid=SEAdvert_Google_SEARCH_AT_Gen-E_c_Jobs_jobs_FPd_EtaId4-L1&loc_interest=&loc_physical=1000852&s_kwcid=AL!524!3!494891721515!e!!g!!jobs")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

your_competence = driver.find_element_by_name("ke")
your_competence.send_keys(search_job)

your_city = driver.find_element_by_name("ws")
your_city.send_keys(search_city)

if "Vollzeit" == search_working_times:
    vollzeit = driver.find_element_by_id("ch1").click()
```

When i run this code anything else except the click in the button
the console displays the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="quickfilters__list-item-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="wt" value="80001" id="ch1"> is not clickable at point (21, 307). Other element would receive the click: <section class="prompt-container">...</section>
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

Could someone pls help me with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your code and it looks like this is happening because of the pop up window with terms and rules. Just add `driver.find_element_by_id("ccmgt_explicit_accept").click()` to your code before trying to use page. With code like this all worked good:

```
    search_job = input("Write your job that you are searching for: ")
    search_city = input("Write your city where you want to find your job: ")
    search_working_times = input("Write your working times: ")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(
        "https://www.stepstone.at/?gclid=CjwKCAiApNSABhAlEiwANuR9YAJKRjy_7hDuKPpJRL-zfaqDqc2zlAo9EgGmRHgs1Bvx5WRu_3ZPkBoC9_cQAvD_BwE&&ef_id=CjwKCAiApNSABhAlEiwANuR9YAJKRjy_7hDuKPpJRL-zfaqDqc2zlAo9EgGmRHgs1Bvx5WRu_3ZPkBoC9_cQAvD_BwE:G:s&cid=SEAdvert_Google_SEARCH_AT_Gen-E_c_Jobs_jobs_FPd_EtaId4-L1&loc_interest=&loc_physical=1000852&s_kwcid=AL!524!3!494891721515!e!!g!!jobs")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    driver.find_element_by_id("ccmgt_explicit_accept").click()

    your_competence = driver.find_element_by_name("ke")
    your_competence.send_keys(search_job)

    your_city = driver.find_element_by_name("ws")
    your_city.send_keys(search_city)

    if "Vollzeit" == search_working_times:
        vollzeit = driver.find_element_by_id("ch1").click()
```

Comment: Thank you it worked
I have one more question I would like to click the button "Find Jobs" automatically so that the website shows me the jobs, when I tried it with this code 'find_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-primary jsForce").click()' it comes to the message 'find_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-primary jsForce").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: It's because you are trying to find multiple elements with class name ("btn btn-primary jsForce"). You need to be carefull with with choosing correct function as `find_element_by_class_name` give you this exact object and `find_elementS_by_class_name` returns list of all objects matching this class name. You can iterate over them and use click function but you cannot click on list.

Comment: Thanks i have always wondered why there are two functions and i have never noticed the difference, till now!